# Probelms: Recreating Netcat in Python3 using the Blackhat Python Book

Tags: python-3.x

help I am a beginner, I am running kali on AWS free tier, i am trying to recreate netcat using python. I was able to compile it but only the -h command works when i run it, its not listening(-l). please help. am adding some random text because its not letting me submit this question. i am using the book blackhat python and a you-tube series on it

```
import argparse
import socket
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys
import textwrap
import threading

def execute(cmd):
    cmd = cmd.strip()
    if not cmd:
        return
    output = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(cmd),stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return output.decode()

# the engine of netcat
class Netcat:
    def __init__(self,args,buffer=None):
        self.args = args
        self.buffer = buffer
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, sock.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        
    def run(self):
        if self.args.listen:
            self.listen()
        else:
            self.send()
                    
    #if we are not running a listener
    def send(self):
        self.socket.connect((self.args.target , self.args.port))
        if self.buffer:
            self.socket.send(self.buffer)
            try:
                while True:
                    recv_len = 1
                    response = ''
                    while recv_len:
                        data = self.socket.recv(4096)
                        recv_len = len(data)
                        response += data.decode()
                        if recv_len < 4096:
                            break
                        if response:
                            print(response)
                            buffer = input('>')
                            buffer += '\n'
                            self.socket.send(buffer.encode())
            except KeyboardInterrupt:   
                print('User terminated.')
                self.socket.close()
                sys.exit()
                                                
    #if we are running a listener
    def listen(self):
        self.socket.bind((self.args.target, self.args.port))
        self.socket.listen(5)
        while True:
            client_socket, _ = self.socket.accept()
            client_threading = threading.Thread(target=self.handle,args=(client_socket,))
            client_threading.start()
                        
    def handle(self, client_socket):
        if self.args.execute:
            output = execute(self.args.execute)
            client_socket.send(output.encode())
                                
        #if argument for file upload is passed   
        elif self.args.upload:
            file_buffer = b''
            while True:
                data = client_socket.recv(4096)
                if data:
                    file_buffer += data
                    print(len(file_buffer))
                else:
                    break
                                    
            with open(self.args.upload, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(file_buffer)
            message = f'Saved file {self.args.upload}'
            client_socket.send(message.encode())
                                        
        elif self.args.command:
            cmd_buffer = b''
            while True:
                try:
                    client.socket.send(b' #> ' )
                    while '\n' not in cmd_buffer.decode():
                        cmd_buffer += client_socket.recv(64)
                    response = execute(cmd_buffer.decode())
                    if response:
                        client_socket.send(response.encode())
                    cmd_buffer = b''
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'server killed {e}')
                    self.socket.close()
                    sys.exit()
                                        
                                    
                                                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='BHP Net Tool',
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    epilog=textwrap.dedent('''Example:
    netcat.py -t 192.16.1.108 -p 5555 -l -c #command shell
    netcat.py -t 192.16.1.108 -p 5555 -l -u=mytest.text #uplod file
    netcat.py -t 192.16.1.108 -p 5555 -l -e=\"cat /etc/passwd\" #execute command
    echo 'ABC' | ./netcat.py -t 192.16.1.108 -p 135 #echo text to server port 135
    netcat.py -t 192.16.1.108 -p 5555 #connect to server
    '''))
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--command', action='store_true', help='command shell')
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--execute', help='execute specified command')
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--listen', action='store_true', help='listen')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int,default=5555, help='specified port')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--target', default='192.168.1.203', help='specified IP')
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--upload', help='upload file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    if args.listen:
        buffer = ''
    else:
        buffer = sys.stdin.read()
            
        nc = NetCat(args, buffer.encode())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't call the `run` function at any point of the script.

Also here you made a simple syntax error:

```
[...]    
elif self.args.command:
            cmd_buffer = b''
            while True:
                try:
                    client.socket.send(b' #> ' )
                    while '\n' not in cmd_buffer.decode():
                        cmd_buffer += client_socket.recv(64)
                    response = execute(cmd_buffer.decode())
                    if response:
                        client_socket.send(response.encode())
                    cmd_buffer = b''
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'server killed {e}')
                    self.socket.close()
                    sys.exit()
```

It's `client_socket.send(b' #> ' )` not `client.socket.send(b' #> ' )`.

Hope I've been helpful!

Comment: works great. love you man no homo. there is also a typo with netcat in code. please I will be back with more questions